# UIView getting resized without my authority

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

Behold a simple view controller:

[image]

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {

    if (!self.viewHasAppeared) {
        self.viewHasAppeared = YES;
        self.testView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
    }
}
```

This code should set the frame of the view to 0, 0, 100, 100. However there are a couple problems. First, this code gets called twice, even though I'm setting a flag so that it only happens once.

The first time through, I see this:

```
<UIView: 0x7e3a5240; frame = (0 0; 100 100); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7e3a4bc0>>
```

The second time through, I see this:

```
<UIView: 0x7e3a5240; frame = (80 142; 160 284); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7e3a4bc0>>
```

Why is the frame getting set back to it's original size?

Yes, I'm using auto-layout. But I don't want this view to have constraints. I tried this:

```
[self.testView removeConstraints:self.testView.constraints];
```

but it didn't help.

Comment: You shouldn't set frames when you're using auto layout. Either turn off auto layout, or change the frame indirectly, by changing the constraints. I'm not sure why removing the constraints didn't work; maybe because testView's superview also has constraints for it.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've always manipulated frames in viewDidLayoutSubviews, even when using auto layout. Not sure why it isn't working this time.

Comment: I don't understand why it would have ever worked, if you're talking about views you made in IB. If it worked for you in the past, I would like to see an example of where that was successful.

Comment: are you sure that the line self.viewHasAppeared = YES is being called twice? or is your breakpoint just in viewDidLayoutSubviews? if you don't want the view to have constraints, do you mean that you want the view to stay a certain size? with autolayout the best way to update your view sizes programmatically is to actually set a NSLayoutConstraint for the width and height, and change those values.